# “WindowServer Died” on login after updating MacBook Pro to latest version of High Sierra

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, login, high-sierra

Right now I am completely unable to log in to my MacBook Pro 2013. This began since attempting the most recent OS X High Sierra update from the App Store. Presumably it failed.

I have tried all the usual approaches (disk repair, fsck, PRAM reset, SMC reset, reinstall OS in recovery mode), to no avail.

Here’s what I get when I boot in verbose mode (Cmd + Shift + V) and then proceed to enter my password and log in.

[image: login screen]

Comment: Have the same problem on the same laptop. There doesn’t seem to be any way to rollback

Comment: Please add to your question if you were using `Filevault`.